# cannot find mfc100d.dll to debug on visual studio 13

Tags: windows, visual-studio, mfc

I want to debug an old application originally developed with Visual Studio 10. I use VS2013, and when I try to run it with debug, an error message appears, saying that "mfc100d.dll is missing". On my Windows System32, I only have dll release version: mfc100.dll.
I setted the projects's version to 120, so I guess it shouldn't need mfc100...

How can I get this file, or use the dll release version ?

Comment: please can you show the complete error message?

Comment: The debug versions of the MFC binaries are part of Visual Studio. You're either going to have to acquire Visual Studio 2010, or recompile the code on a version of Visual Studio you have installed.

Comment: The error message is in french. It's something like: "The application can't start because mfc100d.dll is missing from your computer. Try to reinstall the application and fix this problem

Comment: I already compiled the application with VS2013. And it stills need mfc100. I don't know if it's normal

Comment: Check if project settings have "toolset: Visual Studio 2010".

Comment: Did you ever resolve this by going to project properties -> General -> Platform Toolset and selecting 'your' toolset?

Comment: Yes, my projects are all upgraded to "Visual Studio 2013 (v120)". And I can't choose VS 2010